# WCF and Any Other System

Tags: wcf

If I create a WCF service can it be used by any other system (legacy etc.) that can make use of HTTP GET and POST?
I would like to open up our system with WCF.

Comment: Yes you can build Restful WCF services (webHttpBinding) that operate on HTTP GET/POST protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course yes. WCF provides interoperable bindings like BasicHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding. They can be consumed from other platforms.

have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730017.aspx